# Question of linear map

Tags: linear-algebra

I am appreciated your help

> Consider the linear map, $T\in\mathcal L\left(\mathcal P_3(F), F\right)$ given by the formula $$T_p = \int_0^1 x^2p(x)\, dx.$$ 
> (a) Compute (with proof) a basis for null $T$ and range $T$. 
>  (b) Compute $\mathcal M(T)$ with respect to the monomial basis. 
>  (c) Let $S\in\mathcal L\left(P_3(F)\right)$ denote the change of basis operator which transforms vectors from the monomial basis to the basis, $B:= \left\lbrace x - 1, x + 1, (x - 1)^3, (x + 1)^3\right\rbrace$. Compute $\mathcal M(S)$ and use it to compute $\mathcal M(T)$ with respect to $B$.

Comment: What is the question here?

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you running into trouble?

Comment: I've finished question a, but I don't know how to solve b and c